# delete method problem on flask api, delete() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python

I'm trying to make an api for my website.
on my website you can make and delete posts.
I'm trying that the api will take the post id and delete him,
you need to write your email and password and if they are good and you have a permission to delete the post' it deletes.
but in the second code, it does to me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject33\tryyyy.py", 
line 3, in <module>
c = requests.delete("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/delete_post/3", 
{"email":"example@gmail.com","password":"111111"})
TypeError: delete() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

This is the code,
thank you

```
class delete_post(Resource):
     def delete(self,post_id):
         args = delete_post_args.parse_args()
         email = args['email']
         password = args['password']
         user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
         if user:
             if check_password_hash(user.password,password):
                 post = Post.query.filter_by(id=post_id).first()
                 if not post:
                     return abort(404,message="Post doesn't exists")
                 elif post.author != user.id:
                     return abort(404,message="You can't delete this post because it's not yours")
                 else:
                     db.session.delete(post)
                     db.session.commit()
                     return abort(404, message="Password is incorrect")
             else: return abort(404, message="Post deleted")
         else: return abort(404, message="Email doesn't exists")



  api.add_resource(delete_post,"/api/delete_post/<int:post_id>")
```

and this the the second code

```
import requests

c = requests.delete("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/delete_post/3", 
{"email":"example@gmail.com","password":"111111"})
print(c.json())
```

Comment: `data` is a keyword-only argument, you need to specify it explicitly, i.e. `requests.delete(<URL>, data={...})`. You can also use `json` argument instead.

Comment: It seems you are wanting to call `delete()` on your `delete_post` class, but you’re calling `delete()` on the `requests` module.